# SQL Alias of joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, alias, outer-join

I have a query like this:

```
select a1.name, b1.info 
 from (select name, id, status 
         from table1 a) as a1
right outer join (select id, info 
                    from table2 b) as b1 on (a1.id = b1.id)
```

I only want to include everything where a1.status=1 and since I'm using an outer join, I can't just add a `where` constraint to table1, because all info from table2 that I want to be excluded will still be there, just without the name. I was thinking something like this:

```
 select z1.name, z1.info 
   from ((select name, id, status 
            from table1 a) as a1
right outer join (select id, info 
                    from table2 b) as b1 on (a1.id = b1.id)) as z1 
  where z1.status = 1
```

but I don't think that's legal.

EDIT:
As described below, an outer join actually doesn't make sense for what I'm trying to do. What if, for example, I want all the data from table2 where status!=1 in table1, inclusive of all data where a corresponding ID does not at all exist in table1. Thus I would need an outer join of all data from table2, but still want to exclude those entries where the status=1.

Equivalent to this:

```
 select z1.name, z1.info 
   from ((select name, id, status 
            from table1 a) as a1
right outer join (select id, info 
                    from table2 b) as b1 on (a1.id = b1.id)) as z1 
  where z1.status != 1
```

Comment: I think I realized my problem... an outer join doesn't really make sense for what I'm doing. If the status needs to be 1, that means the record must exist in table1, so I should be using an inner join anyway.

Comment: @Lincecum - In response to some of your comments - I don't think you understand how the `JOIN` s work.  A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` shows you all records in your first table, and then any matching records from the second (or `NULL` if there is not a match).  A `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` does the opposite - all records from table 2, matching only in table 1.  An `INNER JOIN` shows you only where the criteria matches/records exist in BOTH tables.

Comment: Actually, I understand quite well what a Join does. I was initially fetching all the data from table2 using the right outer join to ensure I got all that data regardless of whether a corresponding ID existed in table1. I have since decided I needed only the data from those who were active, which is indicated by table1's status. I was trying to make this modification without realizing that an outer join becomes pointless if a corresponding record with an active status MUST exist in table1.

Comment: @Lincecum - Super, I didn't mean to be condescending or insulting if I came across that way.  Joins are one of the most often misunderstood aspects of SQL, that's all :)

Comment: No worries, my question didn't exactly make sense logically, so I see how you could take it as my own misunderstanding of the concept. I think my revised question makes sense though.

Comment: @Lincecum - it does, but a where in the subselect will give what you are after.  I added to my answer below.  You will still be getting `NULL` values for table 1,  though.  there's no way around that one with an outer join.

Answer (score 15):

```
SELECT a1.Name, b1.Info
FROM table2 b1
    JOIN table2 a1 ON b1.id= a1.id AND a1.status = 1
```

A right outer join does the exact same thing as a left outer join, with just the tables switched. You can filter on the join and it will still include the data from the initial table.

Answer (score 3):

Add the `where` clause to the `subquery` like this:

```
select a1.name, b1.info from
(
    select name, id
    from table1 a  
    where a.status = 1
) as a1

right outer join

(
    select id, info 
    from table2 b
) as b1 on (a1.id=b1.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a1.name, b1.info from
(select name, id, status from table1 a WHERE status=1) as a1
right outer join
(select id, info from table2 b) as b1 on (a1.id=b1.id)
```

EDIT:

For your second scenario:

```
select a1.name, b1.info from
(select name, id, status from table1 a) as a1
right outer join
(select id, info from table2 b) as b1 on (a1.id=b1.id)
EXCEPT
select a1.name, b1.info from
(select name, id, status from table1 a WHERE status<>1) as a1
right outer join
(select id, info from table2 b) as b1 on (a1.id=b1.id)
```

That should work since you will get all the table2 data regardless.

EDIT 2:

OK, to get everything from table2 EXCEPT where there is a status ID in table 1, even if there is not an entry in table1, you need to use the `EXCEPT` function, which will basically exclude a subset from a larger dataset.

Comment: See above. Since this is an outer join, this won't work. It won't actually exclude all the stuff being pulled from table2.

Comment: Is there another reason you need to do a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` on this instead of left or inner?  In most cases a `RIGHT JOIN` is pretty much never called for.

Comment: Not really, as long as it's an outer join

Comment: Make it a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and problem solved, unless you need orphan records from your table2.

Comment: I did want all records from table2 initially, until I realized it doesn't really make sense in this scenario. Still, I feel like there might be a scenario where I would want to check constraints after performing an outer join, and I don't think any of the solutions solve that. Maybe that scenario just doesn't exist though.

Comment: @Lincecum - I think those two criteria cancel each other out.  If you do an outer join, then you want the data without a match in the other table.  If you do an inner join you don't want it.

Comment: Check my edit to the original question. What if I want everything where status!=1, including all data with no corresponding row in table1?

Comment: @Lincecum - see edit to the answer.  You just need to change the query I posted initially to use an inequality `<>` in the where clause of the subselect.

Comment: But this query would still fetch everything from table2 even if its ID corresponds to one with a status not equal to 1 in table2. I don't want the data from table2 to be fetched if its ID has a corresponding entry in table1 with a status of 1.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "even if its ID corresponds to one with a status THAT IS equal to 1."