# MySQL: Alias of Joined Tables - troubleshooting

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a working example on SQL fiddle here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e75d6/34

with the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (Orders JOIN 
     Salesperson ON 
     Salesperson.ID = Orders.salesperson_id) 
      JOIN 
     (SELECT salesperson_id AS sid, MAX( Amount ) AS MaxOrder
      FROM Orders
      GROUP BY salesperson_id) AS TopOrderAmountsPerSalesperson
     ON (TopOrderAmountsPerSalesperson.sid=Orders.salesperson_id AND
         TopOrderAmountsPerSalesperson.MaxOrder=Orders.Amount)
```

but when I try to assign an alias to the first joined table, as shown here:

```
SELECT *
FROM (Orders JOIN 
     Salesperson ON 
     Salesperson.ID = Orders.salesperson_id) AS SalesOrders
      JOIN 
     (SELECT salesperson_id AS sid, MAX( Amount ) AS MaxOrder
      FROM Orders
      GROUP BY salesperson_id) AS TopOrderAmountsPerSalesperson
     ON (TopOrderAmountsPerSalesperson.sid=SalesOrders.salesperson_id AND
         TopOrderAmountsPerSalesperson.MaxOrder=SalesOrders.Amount)
```

I get a syntax error. Any ideas why?

I am using this SO as a resource for aliased joined tables:
[SQL Alias of joined tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071909/sql-alias-of-joined-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give an alias to either the whole query OR a table name OR a field name, but not on a join condition. Try the following example with an alias to the `Orders` table as `SalesOrders`.

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders AS SalesOrders JOIN 
     Salesperson ON 
     Salesperson.ID = SalesOrders.salesperson_id 
      JOIN 
     (SELECT salesperson_id AS sid, MAX( Amount ) AS MaxOrder
      FROM Orders
      GROUP BY salesperson_id) AS TopOrderAmountsPerSalesperson
     ON (TopOrderAmountsPerSalesperson.sid=SalesOrders.salesperson_id AND
         TopOrderAmountsPerSalesperson.MaxOrder=SalesOrders.Amount)
```

Check [<kbd>**SQL Fiddle**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e75d6/41)

Comment: I cant understand what you say. please explain again

Comment: You are a life saver! I am still confused. Does my original join, `Orders JOIN Salesperson ON Salesperson.ID = Orders.salesperson_id`, return a table? If it returns a table, why can't I assign an alias to this table? From my original question, I do not understand why `(Orders JOIN Salesperson ON 
     Salesperson.ID = Orders.salesperson_id) AS SalesOrders` does not work.

Comment: `(Orders JOIN Salesperson ON Salesperson.ID = Orders.salesperson_id) AS SalesOrders` This is join condition and that does not return table